# Do I get valid profiling results with optimization turned off?

Tags: c++, optimization, profiling

I use perf to profile my application. To make interpretation of the resulting call graph easier, I partitioned my core loops using *label functions* like `maptable_appendRange` that can be easily searched for in the call graph. Unfortunately, these functions are mostly inlined by the optimizer and therefore do not show up in the call graph.

To fix this, I can compile without optimization (`-O0`) and everything is fine and profiling with my *label functions* is a bliss. On the other hand, optimization has quite an impact on my code's overall performance and I'm not sure if profiling without optimization will be representative of actual performance.

So here is my question: can I expect representative results when profiling unoptimized code?

Comment: profiling is profiling, it is against the code you built no matter how you built it.  If optimized then that is what you are measuring, if not optimized, then that is what you are measuring.  If you are wanting to use one measurement of one thing to mean something for the other, that makes no sense.  You nave to measure the thing you are using and use those results, cant measure something else.  The price of tea in china has nothing to do with the temperature in Texas.

Comment: A better analogy is having the same driver (source code) do laps in a minivan and laps in sports car and somehow try to use the minivan lap time to talk about the sports car lap times.

Comment: To stick with your analogy, in my use case I am  interesed in the driver's performance and not so much in the cars.

Comment: which you really cant do in this situation, the output is expected to be vastly different in ways that are somewhat predictable with experience but that doesnt mean the profile will see that.  We can tell what the optimizer will do with local variables and if it will inline functions or not, where the cliffs are with respect to all in registers or falling off the cliff and having to use the stack, etc.   But the profile is of both micro and macro taken at the same time ideally.  A sports car vs a yugo.

Comment: No matter how great the driver they cannot make any car perform through the same corner on the same track in a proportional way.  In one vehicle the straights are the problem in another it may be the corners.  Sometimes the profiler will find the same bottleneck but that may be just dumb luck for that one application, for another it may find another place.

Comment: If code C1 is faster than code C2 when optimization is off, but C2 is faster than C1 when optimization is on, then you will have to choose which result is more useful to you based on how you plan to use the result. In particular, if you want to choose between C1 and C2, AND you want to maximize the performance with optimizations on, then you should benchmark C1 and C2 with optimizations on. Also, you will want to minimize instrumentation (extra code inserted into the executable for measurement) because instrumentation is also an overhead.

Comment: If you lose your wallet, and it is dark, do you look for it under a street light where it would be easy to see, or in the dark place where you lost it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You gotta ask *why* you are profiling.

1. To get general performance measurements.
2. To find ways to make the code go faster yet.

If the answer is 1, then by all means, run your profiler on the optimized code.

If the answer is 2, then don't. Here's why.
There are two kinds of speedups, the ones you can do, and the ones the compiler can do.

The compiler cannot find or fix the speedups you can do, such as minimizing memory allocation, memoizing functions that get called with repeat arguments, avoiding innocent-looking library calls that end up doing breezy I/O, on and on.

*There is no speed bug you can fix that is made any more evident by the optimizer.*

What it can do is make them harder to find by scrambling the code, randomly inlining, getting rid of stack frames, etc.
And keep in mind, the only improvement it can actually make is at the bottom of the call stack, and only if it's in *your* code.
Anything it does higher up the stack is of minimal/negligible benefit.

The strategy some people use is [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771),
and the statistical reason why it works is [*here*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262).
After having done that enough to make the code blazingly fast *without the optimizer*, then turn on the optimizer to make it faster yet.

Comment: I think your answer comes close to what I thought off. 

My application uses parallel task execution and I want to find scalability bottlenecks in my algorithms. These bottlenecks are caused by algorithmic choices whose tradeoffs will not be altered drastically by optimization. Therefore I probably can profile unoptimized code.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the profiling results to be meaningful, you should [use the optimization flags that you intend to use in production.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4752944)

That said, you can tell most compilers to never inline specific functions. For example, if you use gcc you could mark your label functions with [`__attribute__((noinline))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bnoinline_007d-function-attribute-3269):

```
__attribute__((noinline)) int func()
{
    ...
}
```

(Other compilers usually provide similar extensions.) This should allow the label functions to show up in the profile even when optimizations are enabled. Keep in mind that the attribute is gcc-specific, so remove it once you're done profiling, or wrap it in a macro that evaluates to nothing if a different compiler is used.

Of course, if the inlining of these specific functions actually has a significant impact on performance, the profiling results might still not be fully representative.

Comment: This is common wisdom, taught in schools or by people with high rep scores on stackoverflow. But it is based on a hidden assumption, namely that there are no further speedup opportunities in the code, and all you want to do is time things. If you are looking for those speedups, the code's being optimized does not help. It can steer you away from some low-level routine that the compiler can optimize, but other than that, it doesn't help in telling you what you *can* fix.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: How about just adding -fno-inline or similar on top of normal options to keep the profile accurate?

Comment: @Deduplicator: You can do that if you want, but it still scrambles the code and keeps some variables in registers, even if it's in functions that are nowhere near the bottom of the call stack, so optimizing them doesn't help. If you want line-level information, this scrambling makes it impossible to get. Besides, if by "accurate" you mean "measuring time with precision", that does not tell you what speed bugs you have. For that, you need *precision of location/situation*, not precision of timing.